# Radial acceleration of a charge also causes electromagnetic field to appear?

Tags: electromagnetism

Accelerating charged particle generates electromagnetic field. Any acceleration vector can be divided into normal acceleration and tangential acceleration.

Does any non-linear trajectory (=> non-zero normal acceleration) of a charge causes electromagnetic filed?

Does a speeding along a straight line charge also causes electromagnetic filed?

*Only normal acceleration* (tangential acceleration being zero - rotation in a circle at a constant linear speed) also *causes charged particle to emit electromagnetic waves?*

Likewise, only tangential acceleration (normal acceleration being zero - moving along a straight line) also causes charged particle to emit electromagnetic waves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's called *synchrotron radiation.*. Huge accelerators are built just to produce it.

Answer (score 0):

Acceleration along a straight line also causes emission of electromagnetic waves.  If the charge accelerates back and forth along a line, it emits electromagnetic waves in a pattern known as [dipole radiation](http://web.mit.edu/course/urop/8.emfields/Public/animations/dipole_far_W20.avi) .